# Dropbox systemd service works but no icon appears

Tags: services, systemd, dropbox

I added dropboxd as a service using the following dropbox.service unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description = Dropbox Daemon
After = network.target

[Service]
User = john
ExecStart = /home/john/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd

[Install]
WantedBy = graphical.target
```

Once I enable it, it works in the sense that dropboxd is running and syncing, but the dropbox icon doesn't show up in the upper right corner like it does when I start dropboxd manually in the terminal.  The main reason I care is because I want to be able to open the settings and adjust the selective sync folders.  Is there another dependency I can add to the unit file to make that icon show up like normal?

Comment: Also, I tried adding lightdm.service as a dependency along with network.target and that didn't do it.

Comment: This question is about systemd just as much as dropbox.  That other question doesn't mention systemd at all.

Comment: Then you should amend your question to reflect what it is that you are asking...