# sudo ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd not working on cron job

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, sync, dropbox

I have used this command directly with the command line and it working fine.

`sudo ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

But when I set it to run each minute with cronjob nothing happens.
my crontab file

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * sudo ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
@hourly wget -qO /dev/null https://mysite.com/cron/KpFh734nRJIBMtAAH1-32ajb8Rv23A-l0pBVg$
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Does using root crontab count as possibility ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command

Comment: I tried this as well, not working!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, `crontab` is not aware of environment variables.
You should indicate the full path. In this example it may be:

```
/home/youruser/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

`sudo` may need a password, so it may not achieve what you expect in a cron job.
It may just be an example, but I am puzzled by the fact that you need to run the Dropbox deamon every minute.

Comment: I try this `* * * * * dev.ecc /home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and `* * * * * root /home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` but not working

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use sudo, or are you escalating privilegies just because it doesn't work without? I think you may have messed up permissions in your `/home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist` folder. You may want to straighten this up with a `chmod -R dev.ecc:dev.ecc /home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist`

Comment: in this command `sudo ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` it not working without sudo, and when I use that it working and files can sync with dropbox, and also up to when the command running, just when I ctrl+c it stop and sync process stop.

Comment: It should be working without higher privilegies. See my previous edited comment to sort this up. Then, you do not need to restart the synchronization daemon every minute. It should tun in the background. From the doc at https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux dropboxd should fork to run in background, but `sudo` may be interfering. Worst case, you could run it with `/home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &` . Notice the ampersand (&) at the end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be `sudo`. Should be the user name. And don't use `~` , use absolute path. like

```
* * * * * root /home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

or

```
* * * * * user /home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Also please note that in either case, `root` or `user` should have execute permission on the script.

Comment: I try this `* * * * * dev.ecc /home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and `* * * * * root /home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` but not working

Comment: can you share the permissions of the file `ls -lrsth /home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

Comment: it returns>ls: cannot access '/home/dev.ecc/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd': No such file or directory, but as I said in my question the command works with command line

Comment: looks like your username or user directory is different. can you please share output of `ls ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and `echo "$USER"`

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/root/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd': No such file or directory`, actually I have a user by the name of `pomin` that is the main user and then for each project, I have a new user that for this case is dev.ecc.new user, and the next on `root@ip-172-31-21-237:~# echo "$USER"
root`

Comment: with which user you were able to run this `sudo ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` ? if it was **pomin** then this should work ` * * * * * root /home/pomin/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue with change my cron command like this:

`@reboot ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

but this is not enough and I should run another command:

`($HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &)&`

after this for the test when I run this command

`sudo ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

I will see this message that means Dropbox is running, and all changes will sync with Dropbox account immediately.

> Another instance of Dropbox (25068) is running!

Comment: Using @reboot in the crontab can make sense, but using a [service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986060/dropbox-systemd-service-works-but-no-icon-appears) or a planned [task](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37957/how-do-i-manage-applications-on-startup-in-gnome-3) when the desktop environment would be cleaner 1) Ensure that the crontab you are adding this directive to is the crontab of the correct user and 2) Use the full path, and not the ~ shortcut! Do you have an encrypted home folder? Can you post the result of `ps auwx | grep dropboxd` and `mount` before you run it manually?

Comment: The dropbox Linux installed globally on the server, and in my case, I just want it for a specific project.This is the result of first command `pomin    14767  0.0  0.0  12948   912 pts/0    S+   08:40   0:00 grep --color=auto dropboxd`

Comment: From this output, it is clear that `dropboxd` is not running. I let you address the other points and questions from my previous comment.